# Avdmanager creating specified emulator via command CMD

Tags: android-studio, adb, avd-manager

I'm reading documentation of avdmanager and can't figure out how to create emulator with the following specs: Pixel 5 API 30, 6.0 1080x2340 xxhdpi , Android 11.0 x86. any suggestion?